# Audio cutting tool for Linux

Tags: linux, audio

I'm searching for a simple audio cutting and merging tool running on Linux. Ideal would be a Gtk application, but only a nice to have. I know of audacity, but this is a little too much.

Goal is to make it used by an unexperienced user.

Features should be quiet simple:

- cutting mp3/ogg to different files -> e.g. a long files into 3 small ones
- merging 2 sound files to one (concat would be ok)
- saving in different formats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/downloads.php).

- Free and open source
- GTK interface
- can open `mp3` and `ogg`
- fast because it doesn't decode audio
- splits files at specified time
- doesn't merge audio - for that use Audacity

Don't bother downloading it, it's already in Ubuntu repos. So you can install with `sudo apt-get install mp3splt-gtk mp3splt`

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That looks awesome!

Comment: Well, this really seems to do the job. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

How about [audacity](http://gmusicbrowser.org/) ?
It is free, open source, cross-platform. Simplicity may be discussional