# Split MP3 files automatically

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, gui, mp3

I have a few large MP3 files (some 7 hours, some 25 hours) and, sadly my player (car-hardware), does not scan well. So, if I listen up to the 3 hour point and I turn off my car, I must scan back to the 3 hour point (and this actually can take 10 minutes).

I am looking for a tool which can run on Windows, ideally free (but I would pay if necessary), with a graphical interface. The tool should take an MP3 file and a target length (say 10 minutes) and automatically split the one large MP3 into multiple smaller MP3.

I have tried [Slice](http://www.nch.com.au/splitter) and found it to be quite unreliable (it regularly fails on the 25 hour MP3 file). I have tried Audacity but I have to manually mark each spot I want to split (a 25 hour audio will have 150 10-minue marks).

I looked at [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11739/735) on a related question and tried [Sox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/). Unfortunately, I do not see a way for Sox to split, only to combine.

[Mp3splt](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3740/735) looks useful but it's command line. Is there a Windows GUI for it?

The GUI could be simple or complex. The goal is simply to avoid having to re-learn parameters every time my needs change by having a somewhat friendly UI.

Is there anything out there which will do this?

Comment: Dumb question: If everything should go automatic anyway, what for do you need a GUI? I'm not a big Windows guy, but I imagine: create a batch script accepting one parameter (the input file to split), then using the input file's name as basename and create the split files in the same directory. Then place a link/copy of that on your desktop. Now drag-and-drop the files-to-split on it, and you've got your GUI solution.

Comment: Understandable arguments – sorry I couldn't guess so from your question. May I suggest you [edit] it and include what you expect from the GUI: settings it should support, should it show a progress bar, etc.? I now guess you prefer something as simple as possible – instead of anything feature-loaden?

Comment: @Izzy Good point. The question should be clear. I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks John! That makes your point clear – and glad to see answers floating in. Good luck!

Comment: To be clear, you don't mind splititng in mid-song?

Comment: @Mawg I was using this for readings (audio books), not music. I have never had a song file which was so long that I would need to split it.

Comment: Off the top of my head ... In a Gadda da Vida by Iron Butterfly .... We will fall, by the Stooges ... maybe not your cup of tea :-)  Doesn't it annoy you that it might split mid-chapter? I am looking for a similar tool to split music - wonder how it will cope with silences in songs. Hmm, there is an online music database which listens, recognizes & returns meta data. I wonder if there is something similar for audio books.. No technical reason why not …

Comment: @Mawg Actually, if you look at mp3splt below (the accepted answer) you can see it does "silence detection" which seems what you want. I don't care about splitting mid-chapter but I do care about splitting mid-sentence which mp3splt handles fine.

Comment: A good point (+1). In my case, I have a single, large .FLAC, containing an entire album. Since I also have a CUE file to accompany it, I think that I can use http://cue.tools/wiki/CUETools_Download which will examine the .CUE file and use that to split the ..FLAC - possibly in conjunction with an online database, I haven't yes  had time to investigate it fully. This approach is more accurate than detecting silences, BUT, obviously, only if you have a .FLAC and a .CUE file.  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38879/split-an-mp-or-flac-with-an-entire-album-into-individual-tracks

Comment: I'm fairly sure audacity has the capability to male automatic splits based on time, and signal level/volume... and possible other ways. I used it for a similar purpose - splitting a single 2hr MP3 into 10 min segments. https://old.audacityteam.org/help/faq_i18n?s=files&i=split

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [GUI for Mp3splt](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2395). And its dead easy

> Mp3splt-gtk is a utility to split MP3, OGG Vorbis and native FLAC files without any change in quality. Just select begin and an end positions to cut out unwanted audio data and space, or to split entire albums to obtain the original tracks.

- [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winpenpack/files/X-Mp3splt/releases/X-Mp3splt_0.9_rev11.zip/download), extract & start the software
- Select *Batch & automatic split* mode, add as many files as you want
- Choose *Time* as split mode and e.g 600 seconds
- Press *Batch split !* and mp3splt will create subfolders for every input file where your output files are stored in

[image]

Comment: For some reason it does not work for my 30H file, it does up to 4 files then stops, without giving an error

Answer (score 5):

I have used [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html) for years. It is distributed as "freeware", is a Windows program, although I've discovered it behaves well running under Wine on Ubuntu. The longest MP3 file I've used it with was a 2hr 45min recording of Bach's St Matthew Passion -- it handled that very nicely.

The feature set includes:

> - Using Cue sheets, pause detection or Auto cue you can easily divide long files.
> - Track splitting with filename and tag creation

It works "natively" on the MP3, that is, it doesn't decode/re-encode. As I say, I haven't done much with splitting (I use it for other kinds of editing), but the process looks fairly simple:

[image: mp3DirectCut]

(The file loaded for this "demo shot" is a 45-minute BBC Radio 4 podcast.)

You can set split points manually by clicking on the time-scale where you want your split (see cursor position in screen capture, above), then clicking the little "scissors" icon in the lower-left panel. Set cut points, then to split the track select `File > Save split`.

You can also set an "Auto-cue" with `Special > Auto Cue...`, then fill in the boxes:

[image: Autocue]

It's a handy tool. It will do this job, although it will be interesting to see what other suggestions arrive.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called Movie Splitter from Movie Toolbox for large .mp3 files and it is very easy and extremely fast. It works on both movie files and audio files to split them into equal parts. You browse for the mp3 file and select the number of parts you want to split it into and then specify an output folder where you want to put the split files. I split an mp3 audio book file that was 7 hours long into 8 parts and it took only 2 seconds to complete this task. It actually worked so fast that at first I didn't think it had done anything but when I checked the output folder it had already completed the splitting process. The price is $19.

[image: Movie Splitter Screenshot]

[Movie Splitter Website](http://www.movietoolbox.com/splitter.html)