# Audio editing tool where you can cut / trim an mp3 file directly, without re-encoding it?

Tags: audio, mp3, audio-editing

I have some mp3 files that need to be cut in segments (one mp3 file for the start, one separate mp3 file for the middle, and another mp3 file for the end). It can be easily done in any DAW, but DAWs tipically transform the file into a lossless format, then apply all new edits, to then re-encode back to mp3 during export. This process degrades the file twice, once for each mp3 encoding, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Is there a way to cut an mp3 file into time segments (different mp3 files), without having to re-encode the data in the process?

Comment: I believe the two top answers in [this Software Recommendations question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14786/split-mp3-files-automatically/14790), mp3DirectCut and Mp3split, will edit without re-compressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de/) which is a lossless editor for MP3 (and to a degree, MP2 and AAC) audio files, able to provide cuts and crops, copy and paste, gain and fades to audio files without having to decode or re-encode the audio.

I've used it in the past to cut a lot of mp3 files in "batch mode", but you can do precise cuts, etc. I hope it's just what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) but since you want to work on the files directly I would suggest [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/).

However FFMPEG is complicated and only works on the command line. Here is an example of trimming an audio file:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182602/trim-audio-file-using-start-and-stop-times

Comment: I don't believe that Audacity can cut an mp3 without recompressing.